# How to convert our local images to Base64 in Next js using Plaiceholder

Tags: javascript, next.js, placeholder, getstaticprops, next-images

I have been using plaiceholder for getting base64 converted image to pass in blurDataUrl in  next/Image component.

```
export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const { base64, img } = await getPlaiceholder(
        "imagePath",
      { size: 10 }
    );
  
    return {
      props: {
        imageProps: {
          ...img,
          blurDataURL: base64,
        },
      },
    };
  };



 const PageBase64Single = ({ title, heading, imageProps }) => (
        <Image {...imageProps} placeholder="blur" />
);
```

Here I have 2 problems:

1. I want  to keep this **imagePath** dynamic so that I can pass on multiple images and url accordingly in blurDataUrl
2. when I am using this it is giving **fs not found**

Stuck since a long time, kindly help

Comment: Can you show us the full error you're getting?